# Extract Value from Locksmith with SwiftyJson

Tags: ios, json, xcode, swift

I'm trying the value of an access token in Swift. I'm loading the token using [Locksmith](https://github.com/matthewpalmer/Locksmith) like so:

```
  let (dictionary, error) = Locksmith.loadDataForUserAccount("userAccount")
```

This returns the following in the console:

```
 Optional({
    "access_token" = 123123123123123;
 })
```

I'm using SwiftyJSON to extract the value of the access token

```
var access_token =  dictionary["access_token"].stringValue
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
'NSDictionary?' does not have a member named 'subscript'
```

Any idea why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As described at your 'NSDictionary?' Dictionary is an optional. You have to unwrap your optional before extracting stringValue from it. You can safely unwrap it using if let:

**Edit**

taking a hint from Rintaro as mentioned by him LockSmith returns an optional Dictionary so you need to first unwrap your dictionary and them you can unwrap access_token key value

```
if let dictionary = dictionary {
    if let access_token =  dictionary["access_token"] as? Int {  // or as? String
        println(access_token)
    } else {
         println(false)
    }
} else {
    println(false)

}
```

or if it returns a [String:String] Dictionary there is no need to cast the value to String

```
if let dictionary = dictionary {
    if let access_token =  dictionary["access_token"] {
        println(access_token)
    } else {
         println(false)
    }
} else {
    println(false)

}
```

Comment: What is your NSDictionary type ?

Comment: Sorry you probably need to cast it to Int

Comment: As mentioned by Rintaro LockSmith returns an optional Dictionary so you need to first unwrap your dictionary and them you can unwrap access_toke key value

Answer (score 2):

LockSmith returns `(NSDictionary?, NSError?)`:

```
 public class func loadDataForUserAccount(userAccount: String, inService service: String = LocksmithDefaultService) -> (NSDictionary?, NSError?)
```

So, in your case `dictionary` itself is `Optional`:

Try:

```
var access_token =  dictionary?["access_token"] as? String
```

Here, `access_token` is `String?`, it can be `nil`. If you want to store it to `AnyObject` variable, you must unwrap it. For example, using ["Optional Binding"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID333):

```
if let token = access_token {
    // Here, `token` is `String`, while `access_token` is `String?`
    self.access_token = token
}
```

Or more directly:

```
if let access_token =  dictionary?["access_token"] as? String {
    // Here, access_token is `String`, not `String?`
    self.access_token = token
}
else {
    // error handling...
}
```

---

BTW, If you want to use SwiftyJSON, you should create `JSON` object from `dictionary`.

```
if let dict = dictionary {
    var json = JSON(dict)
    var access_token = json["access_token"].stringValue
}
```

Comment: Now when I try to plug that value into parameters, I get the following error: 'String?' is not identical to 'AnyObject'

Comment: "access_token" = 123123123123123 looks like it is stored as [String:AnyObject] but it is actually an Int otherwise it would have "" around it

Comment: @LeonardoSavioDabus `NSDictionary` string representation is not the case: try `println(["access_token":"123"] as NSDictionary)`

Comment: So if it just returns [String:String] there is no need to cast

Comment: @Alex You just need to unwrap two optionals and you might need a conditional cast.

Comment: Ah, gotcha. I can do that. Thanks for you guys' help.